# Change button text on 3D flip

Tags: jquery, animation, transition

I'm trying to create a button that flips over on click, and there's different text on the other side ("Add to list" → "Added!").

I'm running into trouble understanding how to change the text and rotate the element so that it seems like the text is on the other side.

I've been looking at [Transit for JQuery](http://ricostacruz.com/jquery.transit/) but I can't find where text fits into the mix.

Thanks!

Comment: Try breaking the animation into 2 parts with the text changed sandwiched inbetween: the first part of flip, then change the text and then the 2nd part of the flip

Comment: This is possible, but the text is upside down on the other side if you use the `<div>` for the button!

Comment: Then do a translate of 180 degrees on the text div/span if possible?

Comment: An option is to create two faces for the button, place them back-to-back in 3d space, and then rotate the space 180 degrees. You would do a dumbed-down version of a 3d cube where you only worry about the front and back faces: http://css-tricks.com/creating-a-3d-cube-image-gallery/